# hash_many rails 4.0.2 confusion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ruby 2 and rails 4.0.2. I created two models one is Post and second is blog_type.

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :blog_types
 validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

blog_type.rb

```
class BlogType < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts
end
```

Post Model

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | Title        | Text              | blog_type_id|
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Ruby is aweso| Ruby is really ...| 1           |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | SQL.....     | SQL is really...  | 2           |
------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Java is aweso| Java is really ...| 1           |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | QA is...     | QA  is really...  | 3           |
------------------------------------------------------
```

blog_type model

```
---------------------
| id | blog_type    |
---------------------
| 1  | Programming  |
---------------------
| 2  | Database     |
---------------------
| 3  | Testing      |
---------------------
| 4  | Math         |
---------------------
```

Migration files

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateBlogTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blog_types do |t|
      t.string :blog_type_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now on rails console, when I am creating Post object with this command

```
bundle exec rails c --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.2)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
2.0.0p247 :001 > @post = Post.new
 => #<Post id: nil, title: nil, text: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 >
```

so my question is I placed relationship in models, why I am not able to see the effect when I create a model instance? my understanding is when I placed relationship, after that if I will create a post model instance, I can see the bellow

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > @post = Post.new
     => #<Post id: nil, title: nil, text: nil, blog_type_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
    2.0.0p247 :002 >
```

Comment: Can you look at your DB and see that the column exists in the table? Are there any migrations you haven't run yet?

Comment: How did you add the column to the table?

Comment: Try reloading the console. run `reload!`

Comment: @Beartech I added migration files, Do I need to add blog_type_id in post table? or it will automatically set the relationship?

Comment: @meagar I didn't add column in the table? Do I need to add in post table? or it will automatically set the relationship?

Comment: @Santosh yes, I reload! but nothing help

Comment: You need to introduce the column via a migration. If you add columns to a migration, you need to run `rake db:redo`, assuming it was the last migration you ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `blog_type_id` column to your `Post` table.

```
rails g migration AddBlog_type_idToPost blog_type_id:references
```

This will create the migration to add the foreign key to `Post`, open it up and look at it to make sure it says:

```
class AddBlogTypeIdToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :blog_type_id, index: true
  end
end
```

Don't forget to run the migration: `rake db:migrate`.
You can create migrations called just about any name. But if you use a syntax in the name that Rails can't figure out, it will just create an empty migration with that name. There is tons of valuable info [in the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). **Next time** you create a table that has foreign keys you can do it like this:

```
rails g migration CreatePostTable title:string text:text blog_type_id:references
```

Note how the we declare `blog_type_id:references` That tells rails to make that column a foreign key referencing the column called `blog_type_id` in another table. Foreign keys are named with their corresponding table name, so it will look in the `id` column of the `blog_type` table. That way when you have declared your relationships in the model, rails automatically gives you corresponding methods like

```
blog = Blog.new(title: "Ruby is .... (omitted for brevity).., blog_type_id: 1)
```

Now we can call things like:

```
puts blog.name
```

gives us `Ruby is awesome`

```
puts blog.blog_type_id.name
```

gives us 'programming`

don't forget to specify **which** field from `blog_type` you want or you will get a reference to the object itself

```
puts blog.blog_type_id
```

gives you `#<BlogType id: 1, blog_type: "Programming" >` 
which is the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

You have setted the relationship, but you only have created the object `@post`, you haven't set the relationship.

You need to create the post and set the blog_type:

```
post = Post.new
type = BlogType.new

post.blog_type = type
```